# Script not running on Pycharm after Github pull

Tags: pycharm, importerror, pull-request, git-pull

So far I have been using pycharm and running the scripts locally on Pycharm without any issues.
Today I did a pull request from my local to Github branch.
After the completion of pull request, my scripts are not running locally!.
I checked all the settings (Base interpreter, Location, etc.) on pycharm, I corrected those too wherever required.
Still no luck.
I think some setup has been changed or some file has been moved.

Earlier I was getting below error:

> No module named selenium

Now the error is:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Have you tried reverting and just not doing that again what broke running your scripts?

Comment: I kept on checking 'Location' and 'Interpreter', and tried to set it with correct path(even though it was not identifiable if any changes had occurred).
After multiple trial and package downloads, now it is working. I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: Are you using venv? In my noise I feel something like the environment is not well defined / some install gaps. Don't have Pycharm here, only IntelliJ.